# Feign Client prepends HTTP

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, feign

I use Spring Cloud in my microservice project with Eureka and Zuul. I want to communicate between my microservices using a Feign client. Say i have a microservice *Microservice1* and *Microservice2*. In addition, i have the Eureka microservice and the Zuul microservice.

Zuul is configured as follows:

```
zuul:
ignoredServices: "*"
sensitiveHeaders: Authorization
routes:
    empty_calls:
        path: /
        serviceId: microservice1
    microservice1:
        path: /microservice1/**
        serviceId: microservice1
    microservice2:
        path: /microservice2/**
        serviceId: microservice2
host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 10000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
```

In my Microservice2, I have the following Feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "microservice1")
public interface Microservice1Client {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/this_is_a_test",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<Boolean> addTestObject(@RequestBody List<String> userMails);

}
```

My problem is the following: I want the feign client to call my REST service via e.g. localhost:8080/microservice1/test/this_is_a_test. Instead, it calls "http://microservice1/test/this_is_a_test". I don't want to configure the feign client manually using the url attribute - it works automatically in other applications, but not for this specific configuration. Can anybody help me here?

**Edit**

The Eureka dashboard:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure whether I am following your question. Your Feign client is pointing to REST service with ID `microservice1`. Any invocation of method `addTestObject` in `Microservice1Client` will map to  `http://<host>:<port>/microservice1/test/this_is_a_test`. Where is `microservice` coming from?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Any invocation of method addTestObject in Microservice1Client will map to http://<host>:<port>/microservice1/test/this_is_a_test" - Yep, this is what i want. But this is not what it does, it calls "http://microservice1/test/this_is_a_test" - I have no idea why. All microservices are running on the same host.

Comment: Is your Eureka set up correctly? Please post a screenshot of your Eureka dashboard?

Comment: I added the Eureka dashboard (the question is still relevant to me :-S )